# I need to figure out: making sql AND operator work

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make this code work. I need 11 records but get 28 with this query. I can get 11 by uncommenting appointments but that gives wrong records. The AND clause in parenthesis seemingly won't filter. Can anyone give me ideas on what I didn't do correctly?(not the best piece of work) :

```
create table #enc
(birthdate date,pidd numeric(19), id numeric(20),lastn varchar(30),firstn 
varchar(30), cdate date)

insert into #enc
select pp.Birthdate,PP.PID, pp.patientprofileid, pp.last, pp.first, 
cast(CAST(DateAdd(s, CAST(Left(d.CLINICALDATE,Len(d.CLINICALDATE)-6) AS 
DECIMAL(20,0)),'Jan 01 1960') AS DATE) as DATE) as visit
 FROM DOCUMENT d
--INNER JOIN Appointments a
--ON d.AppointmentsId = a.AppointmentsId
INNER JOIN PatientVisit v
ON d.PatientVisitId = v.PatientVisitId
inner join patientprofile pp on pp.PId = d.PID
inner join ORDERS o on o.PID= pp.PId
inner join ORDERCODES oc on oc.CODE = o.CODE

where DOCTYPE in(1)  and d.status in( 's','u','h','a') and d.USRID 
=xxxxx

((((and  o.CODE not in('00100','00103','00110','00113','00126'))))

 and oc.ORDERTYPE not in('t')

AND CAST(VISIT AS DATE) BETWEEN '10/01/2018' AND '10/31/2018' 
    
   
    
 select distinct cdate, * from #enc order by lastn
```

Comment: Your example doesn't run as is. Please post a working example.

Comment: So apparently not every document requires an appointment which explains why the join reduces the number of rows. You'll still have to give us more info about the 17 extra rows though.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By Stack Exchange policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Document table and Appointments table has a many to many relation, meaning a document may have multiple appointment records linked to it. This will result duplicate records. try this:

```
create table #enc
(birthdate date,pidd numeric(19), id numeric(20),lastn varchar(30),first 
 nvarchar(30), cdate date)

insert into #enc
select 
    pp.Birthdate,PP.PID, pp.patientprofileid, pp.last, pp.first, 
    cast(CAST(DateAdd(s, CAST(Left(d.CLINICALDATE,Len(d.CLINICALDATE)-6) AS DECIMAL(20,0)),'Jan 01 1960') AS DATE) as DATE) as visit
FROM DOCUMENT d
INNER JOIN ( 
    select distinct AppointmentsId from Appointments
) a ON d.AppointmentsId = a.AppointmentsId
INNER JOIN PatientVisit v
ON d.PatientVisitId = v.PatientVisitId
inner join patientprofile pp on pp.PId = d.PID
inner join ORDERS o on o.PID= pp.PId
inner join ORDERCODES oc on oc.CODE = o.CODE

where DOCTYPE in(1)  and d.status in( 's','u','h','a') and d.USRID 
=xxxxx

((((and  o.CODE not in('00100','00103','00110','00113','00126'))))

 and oc.ORDERTYPE not in('t')

AND CAST(VISIT AS DATE) BETWEEN '10/01/2018' AND '10/31/2018' 



 select distinct cdate, * from #enc order by lastn
```